# Copy of Parent's pointer without copy in Child

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, copy

Hi this is my first topic. I have the following situation in c++:

```
class A;
class Child;
class Parent;

class A 
{
public:
    Parent *_p;
    A() {}
};

class Parent 
{
public:
    void add(A &a) { a._p = this; }
    Parent() {}
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    A a;
    Child() : Parent() { add(a); }
};
```

The main is quite simple:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
     Child c1,c2;
     c2=c1;
     return 0;
}
```

Currently `c2.a._p` has the same address of `c1.a._p` (I did a copy). I would like to modify A and/or Parent in order to update the pointer `_p` with the correct parent. I cannot change Child, this is the strong limitation of my problem.

Any idea? Is it possible?

Comment: Please post [code that will at least compile](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4AsSri$0). What you posted is not valid.

Comment: _p is not declared in Parent. it is a member of A and has to be called through an object of A. in class A what are you doing with _p?

Comment: Sorry, I correted typos in the code. Now it compiles. I would like to use `_p` in order to access methods of Parent inside A.

Answer (score 0):

As you do `c2=c1` it is obvious that `c2.a._p` has the same address as `c1.a._p`. Basically you tell that c2 should be c1!

**Update**: Giving your comment, then you should do that. It is a bit ugly, but I still don't have the full picture of what you are trying to achieve and why the Class Child cannot be modified. This is some kind of pseudo-C++ code.

```
Parent c1;
Child c2, ....;
c2.a._p = &c1;
```

Comment: I have a master object `c1` and I want to declare N copies of it (`c2 -> cN`). All elements must be equal to `c1`, but I need to update the poiter `_p` to correct Parent. 
I know that standard copy (`c2=c1`) is not sufficient. I would like to enrich the class Parent or A in order to define a new copy able to update `_p`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to explain the problem: also `c1` is Child and `c2.a` should have the address of `c2` after the copy. I can only write the main as written in the question (`c2=c1`). I will update the question as soon as possible with more information. thanks